# Postgresql analog to mysql federated table storage engine

Tags: mysql, postgresql, federated-table, federated-storage-engine

Between DBLink in postgresql (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/dblink.html) and foreign data wrappers (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-foreign-data.html), which one (if any) provides the same level of functionality as mysql's 'federated' storage engine (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-use.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you make a side by side comparison (including limitations):

The db_link contrib offers mostly the same functionality, with a different syntax.

Foreign data wrappers offer roughly the same syntax, with an API that allows you to connect to anything (not just MySQL servers).

Answer (score 0):

plProxy is the closest thing to the federated engine. [plProxy wiki page](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PL/Proxy)